# Why can't I create this controller in my test?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a controller that seems to work very well. I need to write test cases so I added the following in a beforeEach().  The `$controller` is being injected into the beforeEach, as is the `$rootScope` that sources the `$scope`.

```
    createController = function() {
        var x = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            '$scope': $scope
        });
        console.log(">>>>>>", JSON.stringify(x));
        return x;
    };
```

When I call `createController`, `x` logs as `{}`.

I checked the `$scope` being passed in - it looks fine.  I misspelled 'MyCtrl' on purpose and got a reasonable error message.

What would cause the `$controller` object to return an empty object, and not log an error?

Comment: @PSL You are correct. It is hard to find an error that does not exist. #selfbonk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no error to show there*, Because you really have not attached anything on the controller instance, everything is attached to the scope. So you get an empty object, because controller does get instantiated after all. I you use `controllerAs` syntax or attach properties on the controller instance you would be able to see them.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.getFormattedName = function() {
    return "Hi i am " + this.name

  }

}).controller('ctrl2', function($controller) {
  var ctrl = $controller('ctrl');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ctrl));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as ctrl">
  {{ctrl.getFormattedName()}}
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2"></div>
</div>
```

Also note that not everything gets stringified when you use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> JSON.stringify converts a value to JSON notation representing it:
>
> - Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification.
> - Boolean, Number, and String objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion semantics.
> - If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).
>     All symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored, even when using the replacer function.

So just use the specified scope in your case, because that is ultimately the view model.

```
var myCtrlScope = $scope.$new(); //Create a child scope, so you keep it separate
createController = function() {
    var x = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        '$scope': myCtrlScope
    });
    console.log(">>>>>>", myCtrlScope);
    return myCtrlScope ;
};
//And use myCtrlScope to access scope methods and properties attached by instantiating the controller `MyCtrl` using the `$controller` provider.
```